# Dependent Data Validation column script not rejecting input (Apps Script)

Tags: validation, google-apps-script

I made the following script to have a dependent dropdown data validation list for an entire column, however I can't seem to find a way to reject input if it's not valid, even with setAllowInvalid(), which I suspect is because I'm doing an offset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cost Centers");
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

 if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 1) {

   if(activeCell.isBlank()){
     activeCell.offset(0,1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
   }

 var departments = data.getRange(3,26,1,20).getValues();

 var departmentIndex = departments[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 26;

 if(departmentIndex != 0) {
 var validationRange = data.getRange(4,departmentIndex,60);
 var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).setAllowInvalid(true).build();
 activeCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
 } }
 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setAllowInvalid(false)
```

[setAllowInvalid(allowInvalidData)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#setAllowInvalid(Boolean))

> true if the rule should allow input that fails data validation; false if not.

Comment: Thank you for this correction, however it still just shows the invalid warning (top right red marker on sheets), my goal is to reject the input and show a warning if not valid, do you have a solution for this?